# How to update field in user table yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have modified user table to add one column, the column's name is **id_periode**, I have advanced template, so from backend controler i want update that column value. I create controller like this

```
public function actionPindahPeriode($id)
{
   $model2 = $this->findModel2($id);
    if ($model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        $model2->save();
        return $this->render('view', 
            'model2' => $this->findModel2($id),
        ]);

    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Makassar');
    $jam_sekarang = date('h:i:s', time());
    $tgl_sekarang=date('Y-m-d');
    $model_periode = Periode::find()
            ->andWhere(['>','mulai_daftar_ulang',$tgl_sekarang ])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

    return $this->renderAjax('pindah_periode', [
        'model_periode' => $model_periode,
        'model2' => $this->findModel2($id),
    ]);

}
```

The  findModel2 function is like this

```
protected function findModel2($id)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

I render that model into a form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?php $listData=ArrayHelper::map($model_periode,'id',function($model_periode){
                        return $model_periode['nama_periode'].' Tahun '.$model_periode['tahun'];});?>
<?= $form->field($model2, 'id_periode')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt' => '']) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The form is working but i can not update the value  **id_periode** column in table user. There is not error showing,  any suggestion?

Comment: print_r($model2); 
before $model2->save();
check if you are getting 'id_periode' attribute in your model.
alternatively check your common\config\main-local.php and set 'enableSchemaCache' => false.

Comment: Can you please share the model «User» source code, I have the feeling where you are missing some configuration, because I have made this many times. Use Gist if you want.

Comment: @Sumit and @moplin, thank very much for your respon, I have solved my problem, First I try to print `Yii::$app->request->post()` like Gru suggestion bellow, and the result give me the array that have id_periode and the value, so i conclude that i should take the value and give that to the model, so this what i did , `$POST_VARIABLE=Yii::$app->request->post('User');
            $model2->id_periode = $POST_VARIABLE['id_periode'];` and then save the model

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your new attribute `id_periode` has a rule defined in the `public function rules(){}` function, this way `$model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` will assign this value from the data submitted.
2. `$model->save()` returns a bool value whether the record was saved or not. You can use this to your advantage and check whether there are any validation errors.ie:

   ```
   if($model2->save()) {
       return $this->render('view', 
           'model2' => $this->findModel2($id),
       ]);
   } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('pindah_periode', [
       'model_periode' => $model_periode,
       'model2' => $this->findModel2($id),
   ]);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 : Check your column fields in User model's validation rules. You need to shift unwanted column fields from required attribute to safe attribute. 
Option 2 : try `$model2->save(false);`. `false` will override your model rules.

Comment: Option 1: I just have one user model that in common model directory, but the rule is like this `public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }`

Comment: Option 2: i have try `$model2->save(false);` but the value still can not updated, I am  confuse now

Comment: Alternative : Print posted data `Yii::$app->request->post()` to confirm whether you are getting or not. If id_periode is set with value; try `$model2->id_periode = $post_data_for[id_period];` before `$model2->save(false);`

Comment: I have solve my problem, First I try to `Yii::$app->request->post()` like your suggestion, and the result give me the array that have id_periode and the value, so i conclude that i should take the value and give that to the model, so this what i did , ` $POST_VARIABLE=Yii::$app->request->post('User');
            $model2->id_periode = $POST_VARIABLE['id_periode'];` and then save the model

Comment: `$model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` loads only posted model(i.e. table) related data; but `Yii::$app->request->post()` will give u all posted form data. happy coding..!